# How to create enum that takes parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

This is my enum

```
enum urlLink: String {
   case linkOne = "http://test.com/linkOne"
}
```

and it works well in most of my cases. However, I now want to create another link which will takes parameters and it looks like this

```
"http://test.com/:params/info"
```

is there a way that I can add string parameter to one of my enum cases so that I can have something like this for linkTwo

```
enum urlLink: String {
   case linkOne = "http://test.com/linkOne"
   case linkTwo(input: String) = "http://test.com/" + input + "info"
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add raw values to enums with associated values. You can, however add properties and methods to your enum, so you can do something like this:

```
enum urlLink: CustomStringConvertible {
    case linkOne
    case linkTwo(input: String)

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .linkOne:
            return "http://test.com/linkOne"
        case .linkTwo(let input):
            return "http://test.com/\(input)info"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also conform to `RawRepresentable`:

```
enum urlLink: RawRepresentable {
    case linkOne
    case linkTwo(input: String)

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .linkOne:
            return "http://test.com/linkOne"
        case .linkTwo(let input):
            return "http://test.com/\(input)info"
        }
    }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        if rawValue == "http://test.com/linkOne" {
            self = .linkOne
            return
        } else {
            self = // some regex logic to get the "input" part
            return
        }
        return nil
    }

    typealias RawValue = String
}
```

Comment: @KevinVuD Edited. You can also conform to `RawRepresentable`, which is what the enum would have conformed to, if you said `enum urlInk: String`.